# Excel VBA - Msg Box if selected cell is in a range and also meet criteria

Tags: vba, excel, criteria

I'm looking for a vba to popup a `MsgBox` when selected cell is in a range and also meet criteria.

**Example**:

```
Range: (A3:A7)
Criteria: "YES" 

     |        A          |        B         |    
      -------------------|------------------|
  1  |        NO         |                  |
  2  |        NO         |                  |
  3  |        YES        |         1        |
  4  |        YES        |         2        |
  5  |        NO         |                  |
  6  |        NO         |                  |
  7  |        YES        |         3        |
```

**Requirement**: If I double click either A3, A4 or A7, a msg box should appear with the value of the next column in the same row.

**Example**: If I select A7, a `MsgBox` with the value "3" should appear.

I have tried a couple of things with no success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

MD

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started with this. Please note that this code goes into the worksheet object and **not** in a separate module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A3:A7")
    If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            MsgBox (Target.Offset(0, 1))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

also this will still leave the cell in edit mode after the msgbox is dealt with unless you handle that in the code also

Comment: You should enhance this solution with: 1) a check that 'Target' is a single cell range 2) it contains "YES"

Comment: Sorry. missed that out. have revised the code

Comment: @user3598756 BTW, Double click will always happen on a single cell. Do you see any other scenario??

Comment: Double click actually happens on a single cell only

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (put it inside your relevant's sheet's code), it will check if you double-click on any cell in Column A (as long as you have data inside it), and checks if that cell's value equals "YES".

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            MsgBox Target.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```